# How can I prevent PHPUnit from running a PHP file in the Tests directory?

Tags: phpunit, mockery

I have a lot of tests that require a particular mock object to be created. So, here is what I've done:

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Services\Terminal;

use Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\MockeryTestCase;
use AppBundle\Entity\Tunnel;
class TunnelBasedTestCase extends MockeryTestCase
{

    /**
     *
     * @var Tunnel
     */
    protected $tunnel;

    protected function setup()
    {
        $tunnel = new Tunnel();
        $tunnel->setName('B9')
            ->setIp('192.168.2.52')
            ->setUsername('username')
            ->setPassword('password')
            ->setSign('sign')
            ->setStatus('open');

        $this->tunnel = $tunnel;
    }
}
```

However, the problem is that now PHPUnit tries to run this test, which is only meant to prevent me from copy-pasting the `setup()` function. I don't want to skip it, because I want to get a completely green test result instead of getting something like:

```
....S.....
```

Or this:

```
....I.....
```

Here is my PHPUnit configuration that also fails to do this:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <exclude>../src/AppBundle/Tests/Services/Terminal/TunnelBasedTestCase.php</exclude>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: this class is not a `testcase` class, so you can rename it with a name that don't match the regular expression for check if it is a `testclass`. So you can rename it for example in `BaseTunnel `. Hope this help

Comment: I thought of that, but the problem is that I will have to lose readability over this. I first want to make sure that there's actually no way, not that I don't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

you can edit your phpunit.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="foo">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
            <exclude>./tests/path/to/excluded/test.php</exclude>
                ^-------------
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

You can also try to make a blacklist like this:

```
<filter>
    <blacklist>
          <file>../src/AppBundle/Tests/Services/Terminal/TunnelBasedTestCase.php</file>
    </blacklist>
</filter>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made your required changes though, and nothing changed. I've updated my answer to show the code in case I got you wrong.

Comment: I have edit my answer, try now please. Both methods work fine for me

Comment: This one fails as well. I have verified that the file exists by copy-pasting the path into the terminal. I'm using PHPUnit 4.7.7.